# Filter invalid ids from the oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

My table

```
NAME

Peter
Lance
Oscar
Steve
Reddy
```

Input to my query is array of string, let's say `Peter, Bond, Steve, Smith`

My query should return me the invalid values of my input (i.e) `Bond & Smith`

I am using `Oracle 12.1.0` and odcivarchar2list is not supported.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cte` :

```
with list_string as (
     select 'Peter' as name union all
     select 'Bond' as name union all
     select 'Steve' as name union all
     select 'Smith' as name
)
select ls.name, 'Invalid Values'
from list_string  ls
where not exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.name = t.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Some more options.

Data you have:

```
SQL> select  * from test;

NAME
-----
Peter
Lance
Oscar
Steve
Reddy
```

If you don't mind enclosing names into single quotes, then this might be an option:

```
SQL> select column_value result
  2    from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('Peter', 'Bond', 'Steve', 'Smith'))
  3  minus
  4  select t.name
  5    from test t;

RESULT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bond
Smith

SQL>
```

---

If you'd just want to enter those names "normally", comma-separated, then:

```
SQL> with
  2  sample (val) as
  3    (select 'Peter, Bond, Steve, Smith' from dual)
  4  select trim(regexp_substr(s.val, '[^,]+', 1, level)) result
  5    from sample s
  6    connect by level <= regexp_count(s.val, ',') + 1
  7  minus
  8  select t.name
  9    from test t;

RESULT
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Bond
Smith

SQL>
```